# 403 Access denied

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I installed Redmine according to the instructions at https://izolabs.tech/2021/11/install-redmine-on-ubuntu.html on a webserver. Redmine works now at withsystem.de/redmine. But when I go to withsystem.de , I can't see the normal apache2-testsite but an 403 error (as you can check by yourself).
What can I do to fix this? Is the instruction somehow incomplete or contains misstakes?

Here is a log after restarting apache2

```
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3097 2937/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3402 2940/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3406 2940/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3494 2940/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 2940

[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3805 2940/T3 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:670 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3805 2940/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1245 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3807 2940/T9 Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3807 2940/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3807 2940/T3 Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.3807 2940/T3 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4090 2957/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4375 2962/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4377 2962/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4436 2962/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 2962
[Wed Mar 23 01:28:57.447247 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2955:tid 139861455912000] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 23 01:28:57.447414 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2955:tid 139861455912000] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Mar 23 01:28:57.450530 2022] [mpm_event:alert] [pid 2972:tid 139861448599296] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH03104: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4565 2940/T1 age/Cor/TelemetryCollector.h:531 ]: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:57.4775 2940/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-23 01:28:59.5843 2962/T8 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
[Wed Mar 23 01:29:40.158402 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 2973:tid 139861281453824] [client 87.187.170.33:45328] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Mar 23 01:42:04.846173 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 2973:tid 139861239490304] [client 183.136.226.3:39524] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Mar 23 01:42:06.531652 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 2973:tid 139861189134080] [client 183.136.226.3:11043] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Mar 23 01:42:54.847205 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 2973:tid 139861273061120] [client 45.146.165.37:48062] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: A 403 should leave a record in the Apache logs. Check for errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. If you’re uncertain of how to resolve the errors reported, [edit] your question to include the logs so that somebody here might help 

Comment: I think you get this error if there isn't a file `index.html` or `index.php` in the root folder. The default action is then to list the contents of the folder, which the web server doesn't allow. Probably creating an empty `index.html` file will make this error go away.

Comment: Thank you.
@Jos your suggestion didn't work i think

Comment: @matigo i added the log file

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting a 403 when you visit the root site is because you followed the instructions perfectly. This first part of step 5 is why you are getting a 403:

[image: Renaming the HTML File]

Your `error.log` shows this message:

```
No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Which means there is nothing for Apache to show people if they visit the root domain and, because of the `Options` directive (set as `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` in your Apache configuration), you will not see a directory listing.

If you would like to restore the default Apache landing page, you can rename `index.html.bak` back to `index.html`. Alternatively, if you would like the base domain to show a different set of files, you can build the site however you wish.